# Kleene algebra without right distributivity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, formal-languages

I'm facing a mathematical structure that has everything of a Kleene algebra (S, +, ., 0, 1, *), except that the multiplication '.' is not right-distributive over the addition '+'.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_algebra

I reckon that it could be defined as a weakened version of Kleene algebra, where the semiring (S, +, ., 0, 1) is weakened to a (left) near-semiring, but I haven't found that description used anywhere until now.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-semiring

Is there a known name for such a structure, that could hint me to some literature ?

Thanks by advance,

Alex

Comment: I would call it something like '*left Kleene algebra*'. But it doesn't really help in searching.. Can you share us some interesting features/properties/usage of these?

Comment: Well, I am formalizing a description language that mimics the structure of CFGs, but applied on an typed process space. 

My "alphabet" is a set of processes, the natural multiplication '.' is process composition, and the addition '+' is the parallelization of 2 processes.


We also want to be able to "join" the results from two parallel processes if needed, and thus our processes are typed, and
(a + b) is a process that outputs a Pair of results. 

Given a process 'c', we can maybe type (a + b).c or (a.c + b.c), but not both, which yields the contradiction to the right-distributive axiom.

Comment: Also, I found mentions of "left-handed Kleene algebra", but the 'left-handed' part refers to the * axioms of the algebra, and not the distributivity in the semiring...

As for the properties of the structure, if it already has been studied, that is what I am after !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once I ran across [Graphs, Dioids and and Semirings](http://books.google.com/books?id=XudA1RktfCAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=semirings&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rIcjUfnPBKa30AH43ICYCg&ved=0CGAQ6AEwCA) by Gondran and Minoux, and discovered it was a pretty well written book about such things.

I can't be positive it has exactly what you mention, but I remember it contained very detailed nomenclature for organizing generalizations of rings (for example: single-sided axioms, exactly as you are looking for). Since such generalizations have exploded in the past 40 years, and everybody chooses different names for stuff, the authors had a tough task of shoehorning everybody's terminology into a single comprehensible book. It is also pretty new, so I'd start there!

Another one I enjoyed was Golan's [Semirings and their applications](http://books.google.com/books?id=DNdTF_4PzpoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=semirings&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rIcjUfnPBKa30AH43ICYCg&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAw); however, it is much older, and I have even less confidence that it addresses exactly what you are interested in.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointers,  Graphs, Dioids and and Semirings seems indeed to circumvent my field and explore it pretty extensively ; I'll have a peek at it!